# Setar nome propriedade objeto anônimo e resources

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou usando resources para multi-idioma em um sistema.

Em um retorno json eu crio um objeto anonimo

```
var resultado = minhalista.Select(x => new { })
```

Mas acontece que eu preciso que a propriedade desse objeto anônimo seja de acordo com o valor do resource, pois minha View espera o nome de acordo com o resource

Ou seja, sei que não da... mas seria algo tipo:

```
var resultado = minhalista.Select(x => new { Resource.Nome = x.Nome })
```

Então a propriedade deve vir, Nome, Nombre, Name..etc conforme o valor do resource

Há alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Porque a propriedade precisa ser localizada? Isto deveria ser uma informação interna do software e não deveria precisar de localização. Sempre tem um jeito mas pode ser tão complicado que não vale o esforço.

Comment: @bigown é por causa de uma função js que gera o grid já com os head, e outras configurações

Comment: Não conheço toda a mecânica do que está usando mas ela não deveria depender da propriedade, deveria ter uma outra forma de obter esta informação.

Comment: Existe uma propriedade no jquery datatables que é columns, a mesma é passada assim:   { "data": "Nome", }, isso é o que o plugin espera do json, então ele espera "Nome", na minha função eu gero isso e também o thead da table, se realmente não tiver como, o jeito é alterar a minha função em js mesmo então, rs

Comment: Jeito tem mas é tão complicado, tão fora do que deveria ser feito, que normalmente vale mais dar outra solução. A não ser que a outra seja mais complicada ainda :)

Comment: @bigown creio que mudar o js não é tão complicado, irei mudar, obrigado pelas respostas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementei o seguinte método de extensão que cria um objeto dinâmico com nomes de propriedades variáveis. Basicamente, ele pega um objeto qualquer e o transforma em objeto dinâmico:

```
    public static ExpandoObject ObjetoAnonimo(this object obj)
    {
        var retorno = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var property in ReflectionUtils.ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(obj).Where(x => !x.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
        {
            var columnAttribute = ReflectionUtils.ExtrairAtributoColumnDeProperty(property);
            var nomePropriedade = columnAttribute != null ? columnAttribute.Name : property.Name;

            switch (property.PropertyType.ToString())
            {
                case "System.Int32":
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(property.GetValue(obj, null)) > 0)
                    {
                        ((IDictionary<string, object>)retorno).Add(nomePropriedade, property.GetValue(obj, null));
                    }

                    break;
                case "System.Int64":
                    if (Convert.ToInt64(property.GetValue(obj, null)) > 0)
                    {
                        ((IDictionary<string, object>)retorno).Add(nomePropriedade, property.GetValue(obj, null));
                    }

                    break;
                case "System.DateTime":
                    if (Convert.ToDateTime(property.GetValue(obj, null)) > DateTime.MinValue)
                    {
                        ((IDictionary<string, object>)retorno).Add(nomePropriedade, property.GetValue(obj, null));
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    if (property.GetValue(obj, null) != null)
                    {
                        ((IDictionary<string, object>)retorno).Add(nomePropriedade, property.GetValue(obj, null));
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        return retorno;
    }
```

Para o seu caso, bastaria preencher `nomePropriedade` com o nome da resource desejado.

Uso:

```
var objeto = new { ColunaResource1 = valor1, ColunaResource2 = valor2, ... };
var objJson = objeto.ObjetoAnonimo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rod,

Acredito que o caminho mais recomendável seria tipar sua variável resultado.

Exemplo:

```
class Person 
{ 
    public String Name{get;set;} 
    public String Email{get;set;} 
}

var resultado = (from item in minhalista select new Person{ Name = item.Name, Email = item.Email }).ToList();
```

Existe um objeto denominado ExpandoObject ([System.dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) mas não sei se o mesmo é possível ser serializado via Json